# QInputDialog popup without application in Pyside

Tags: python, pyside

How can I make a popup QInputDialog without a parent Application using Pyside?

When the user double clicks this python file I want it to display the Input dialog and that's it.

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

def network_copy():

    text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Test | Network Copy', 'Enter name')

    if ok and text:
        print 'Great'

network_copy()
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly why you cannot create a `QApplication`?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your example, it will print a debug message like this: `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice`. So, obviously, this is just not possible.

I'm guessing that all you want to do is avoid having to start an event-loop. However, this is not an issue with dialogs, because they run their own event-loops. So just create the `QApplication` before showing the dialog:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
network_copy()
```